# Why pass by ref needs shift instead of @_?

Tags: perl

I have a question regarding pass by reference  to subroutines in Perl. For values if I pass using @_ it works but for ref only shift works . Not sure why. I have givedn sample code below:

This works:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $name = 'John';
PassScalarByRef( \$name );

sub PassScalarByRef{
    my $got = shift;
    print "Hello $$got\n";
}
```

but not this one:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $name = 'John';
PassScalarByRef( \$name );

sub PassScalarByRef{
    my $got = @_;
    print "Hello $$got\n";
}
```

Comment: Note: Perl always passes *by* ref. What you are doing is passing *a* ref.

Comment: Note for people coming across this question in the future: This problem has nothing at all to do with pass by reference or pass by value. It has everything to do with list assignment vs scalar assignment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the second case, assigning to `$got` provides a scalar context to `@_`, which causes it to evaluate to its size (number of elements).  You can instead say:

```
my ($got) = @_;
```

...to assign the first element of `@_` to `$got`, as you expect.

Answer (score 6):

You are using the `@_` array in scalar context. `$got` now contains the number of arguments passed. You should try `my ($got) = @_`, which now uses the array in list context which is what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

Most operators give their operands a specific context in a consistent way; for instance, `+` gives both its operands scalar context; `||` gives its left operand scalar context and its right operand whatever context the `||` itself has.

Assignment is a little different, because there are two types, list assignment and scalar assignment.

Scalar assignments look like:

```
$scalar = ...
lvaluesub() = ...
```

(lvalue subs are a little-used feature of perl; the builtin `pos` is an example).

Only one value is being assigned, and these give `=`'s right operand scalar context.

List assignments look like this:

```
@array = ...
@arraytoslice[...] = ...
%hash = ...
@hashtoslice{...} = ...
( ... ) = ...
```

or even

```
() = ...
```

All these expect a list of values to assign, so give the right operand list context.

When you say:

```
my $got = @_;
```

this is a scalar assignment, and so `@_` gets scalar context, which causes it to return its number of elements, not the first value.

Instead, say:

```
my ($got) = @_;
```

Some people do this consistently, even for subs with only one operand; others do

```
my $param1 = shift;
my $param2 = shift;
```

for subs with a small number of operands.

It's common for methods to get the object/class using shift and a list assignment from @_ for the remaining parameters.

Comment: [Mini-Tutorial: Scalar vs List Assignment Operator](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129), my version of your post.

Answer (score 0):

Used differently.

my $got = $_[0];